# How do I install Otter browser on Ubuntu 18.04?

Tags: software-installation, 18.04, browser

This [site](https://otter-browser.org/) doesn't make sense to me although I provides some instruction.

Can someone make it more accessible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's should be pretty easy using a PPA, for example [this one](https://launchpad.net/~otter-browser/+archive/ubuntu/release).

Just do

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:otter-browser/release
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install otter-browser
```

Comment: Thank you! Now I can paste passwords into the browser again!